# How to retrieve all children from Firebase Database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to learn how to use Firebase by creating a simple social media application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfeyw.png (Here is how my database is laid out)

I was able to add data to the database but I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve data. I want to be able to retrieve all the posts from a certain user and then display each one as an item in a list.

```
let Posts = firebase.database().ref('Posts').child(userId);
```

So far thats my query and here is the code I'm using to add the posts to the database. Could someone also tell me what is the term for the Id that is being generated for each post?

```
firebase.database().ref('/Posts').child(userId).push({
      Text: post,
      Score: 0
  });
```

Comment: The id when you push is called a "push id".

Comment: You might want to take a look at the documentation to learn how to read and write data in Realtime Database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks. When there is a push Id how does one find that data? As in the child of "Posts" is the User Id which I know but the Push Id is something I dont know. Do I need to find it out or is there a way of retrieving each child of the User Id. I've read through the example in the documentation and haven't been successfully able to retrive anything.